# Open Graph Action: Using staging site for action approval submission

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have a Facebook app where I've developed 2 Open graph social actions. My development environment has 3 sites - Dev, Staging, Production. I'm currently using 3 different FB app for the 3 sites. The open graph action related works are not deployed to production yet. They are on staging.

My staging site is a subdomain of my production.

My question is, can I simply point my production FB app's URL to my staging site - http://stg.mysite.com and then after the approval process is complete switch the URL to my production site - http://mysite.com ?

Will changing the URL (even though within same domain) of the Facebook App after the action has been approved invalidate the approval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get your action approved while app is using staging site. as once the action has been approved for your application, it does not cause any problem on changing the app url. I have done it for my app.

Comment: Thanks very much Smita. That's a huge relief.

Comment: What about the callback url, the "Site URL" in the app settings? It does not fit if the subdomain is different. Therefore it does not seem to be a good idea to use the same app for both staging and production environments, only one would work at a time. FB.login() does not work if the callback url is not correct.